# What is the "default time to live" (TTL) for Platform Cache?

Tags: apex, platform-cache

The Platform Cache [Partition Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_cache_Partition.htm#apex_class_cache_Partition) allows a time to live to be specified when a value is `put` into the cache:

```
put(key, value, ttlSecs)

Stores the specified key/value pair as a cached entry in the cache
partition and sets the cached value’s lifetime.
Signature

public void put(String key, Object value, Integer ttlSecs)

Parameters

key
Type: String
A case-sensitive string value that uniquely identifies a cached value.

value
Type: Object
The value to store in the cache. The cached value must be serializable.

ttlSecs
Type: Integer
The amount of time, in seconds, to keep the cached value in the cache.

Return Value
Type: void
```

What is the default behavior when a `put` method that does not include a `ttlSecs` value is used for the two cases of:

- `OrgPartioon`
- `SessionPartition`

(FYI [How to get time left on OrgPartition from Platform Cache?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281471/how-to-get-time-left-on-orgpartition-from-platform-cache))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

24 hours as per [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_limits.htm) for Org Cache. No mention for session cache, probably because the session can expire any time?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pranay, I missed that.